# How to print filter after training the network? Just want to see the values of weights of the filter after training the network

Tags: tensorflow

I have a CNN network with one convolution, maximum pooling and one fully connected layer. After training the network I want to see the final value of weights that filter has adopted. What I have to do for this purpose? Should I have to print W matrix of fully connected layer? Should I have to replace some weights?I am training the network using a batch size of 30.

```
`
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0, stddev=0.1)
return tf.Variable(initial)
#network
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 
FLAGS.image_height*FLAGS.image_width])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])



input=tf.reshape(x, 
   [-1,FLAGS.image_height,FLAGS.image_width,FLAGS.input_channel])
filter = weight_variable([FLAGS.filter_size, FLAGS.filter_size, 
   FLAGS.input_channel, FLAGS.filter_channel])
conv_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(input, filter))

pool_out = max_pool(conv_out)


pool_list = pool_out.get_shape().as_list()
input_dim = pool_list[1]* pool_list[2]* pool_list[3]
pool_2D = tf.reshape(pool_out, [-1, input_dim])
W_fc = weight_variable([input_dim, 2])

logits = tf.matmul(pool_2D, W_fc)   #(batch_size,2)
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
s=tf.argmax(y_conv,axis=1)
test = tf.reduce_sum(s)

cross_entropy = 
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.rLearn).minimize(loss)


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,axis=1), tf.argmax(y_, 
axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
#training loop
for i in range(200):`
```

Comment: Is my Question unclear? I have added all necessary information

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the way you initialize the weight matrix.

Assuming that you initialize weigh matrix in this way:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))
```

After training you can retrieve the values of the weight-variables in this way:

```
# Retrieve the values of the weight-variables from TensorFlow.
# A feed-dict is not necessary because nothing is calculated.
w = session.run(weights)
```

Comment: I have updated my code and defined weights matrix. In my code I call weight_variable function twice,once for filter and once for fully connected layer. Does it mean that I have to call weight_variable function after and outside training loop?

Comment: No.  What you have to do is   `w = session.run(weights)`  with the weights defined before.

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get your point. According to my understanding if I print filter.eval()  at the end of  and outside the training loop it gives me the filter values that I want. What is weights in your sess.run? and what do you mean by with weights defined before?

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more